# plotting line graph with error bar in R from cross tabulated data

Tags: data-visualization

I am wondering how could I line plot mean with error bar of cross tabulated data in R package.
My data looks like this

```
Mean 
           Stage
Treatment    breaker        green        pink             red          turning
     cont    0.06779080    0.1964575    0.010335260    0.005861540    0.05828315
     FRM     0.17211680    0.1853831    0.021794200    0.013183020    0.09467819
     KNO3    0.24755945    0.2863050    0.007866763    0.002554247    0.06097948
     LFR     0.08053258    0.1287083    0.008566730    0.000000000    0.07710268
     salt    0.38564291    0.4419331    0.050551620    0.001115087    0.14508939

Standard deviation
         Stage
Treatment    breaker        green        pink            red            turning
     cont    0.01504616    0.14157770    0.003498454    0.0037076134    0.032316651
     FRM     0.02710538    0.03422274    0.017164023    0.0143484928    0.058139975
     KNO3    0.05372195    0.12865178    0.003552846    0.0006738978    0.001983925
     LFR     0.04366554    0.05611974    0.009180117    0.0000000000    0.029396442
     salt    0.03035888    0.12908778    0.028818513    0.0004681397    0.050566535
```

Comment: Error bars representing what? Computed how?

Comment: Hi Glen_b thanks for responding on my second question. If you correctly remember my first question, then you provided me a script to produce cross tab of mean and sd from factorial design data. the table above derived from same script like with(Chlordata, tapply(Chlorophyll, list(Treatment=Treatment,Stage=Stage), mean) ); where Chlordata is my data frame and treatment and and stage are my two factor using witch mean of chlorophyll is tabulated.  I am seeking help on bar graph of same data with SD as error bar. Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information to discern exactly what you want. Both tables are two-dimensional, but bar charts can normally only plot one factor (since the page is 2D and plotting one factor a bar chart is two dimensional - one factor on the x-axis and the height will be the value you're plotting). As such you have to specify how you want to deal with that (grouping, several such plots one above the other, or what). Incidentally a bar chart is not a particularly good way to display this kind of information, so if you have the choice it might be better to pick some other way to display it.

Comment: Thanks Glen-b for your suggestion, as I am newbie in R (started last month) still puzzling. I want Stage values (green, breaker, turning, red and pink--in that order) on X-axis and Treatment wise line plots (several) in one figure (plot).

Comment: I still can't follow. Could you explain what you mean in your actual question? You might also take a look at the comments I made under my answer on your earlier question -- in particular, to consider whether this is really a data vizualization question (like "what's a good way to visualize this?") or pretty much a pure coding question ("how do I produce bar plots with error bars in R?"). If you need to move your question, flag it for moderator attention (rather than repost).

Comment: Sorry Glen_b, forgive me for my writing. I can produce single line graph with error bar with R. However, here the question is how to make a line graph of different treatments together in one plot to see the trend in chlorophyll level change according to growth stage of fruit (green, breaker, turning, pink and red). Further putting SD as error bar is another trivia for me on the same graph. Thanks for responding me.

Comment: If it's a line you're after, rather than a sequence of bars, you can do it relatively easily. Another possibility is to modify a Cleveland dot-chart. If you're looking to plot against several factors, the `lattice` package has some tools that might be of use.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the ggplot2 package in R, examples at

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

I think this is what you are asking.

To summarise the final solution:

- the basic problem was solved without error bars. There were only 3 reps per treatment and  it is better to plot the actual data rather than error bars in this case.
- a few more pre-processing steps were conducted, one was to plot the response variable and notice that the distribution was skewed. A sqrt transformation was done to fix this.
- two plots were produced as the final solution (labels were removed to ensure anonymity of data):

[image] [image]

Comment: I feel remiss in not having welcomed you to the site. We appreciate your taking the time to contribute here. CV is very lucky to benefit from contributors w/ your level of expertise.